# Is it possible to create an AI that produces output without giving it input?

Tags: chat-bots, training-datasets

AFAIK an AI is first trained using a data set of input and output values.
After the training proccess you can give the AI input and it will produce output.
For example when you write a sentence to an AI chatbot it will write an answer.
But is it possible to create an AI that produces output without giving it input?
For example that would mean there is a chatbot saying things without being asked.

Edit: In the training proccess I do not care if input data is used. I want to know if after the training proccess it is possible to create a chatbot (for example) which says things without giving input.

For example when you are on a discord channel it is normal that people start conversations without being asked something.

Comment: Yes, and in fact this is exactly what all of the GPT models (including ChatGPT, I think) do!

Comment: I upvoted the question since i like the topic. I think the question 'is it possible' is not so much the right question as 'is it useful'. yes it is definitely possible to create a machine that just randomly outputs stuff without giving it input. This would be a satisfactory machine for your question. However, whether it is possible to create a useful machine that outputs stuff without giving it any input is a much more difficult question. You hence need to specify your question further. First question would be: do you allow it to train on input data? Or is that input also not allowed?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn See my edit.

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn Do you know why I don't get any results when googeling for "satisfactory machine"?

Comment: Okay, with the edit, it is even more obvious to me that the logical question to ask is 'is it useful'. Like you can indeed just let GPT-3 or some large language model predict the next word without giving it any input. But the output is probably not very useful. So 'is it possible' is definitely yes

Comment: 'Satisfactory machine' is not a term. You stated some set of requirements for your 'algorithm/machine', and i proposed some 'machine' which adhered to those requirements, making it a 'satisfactory machine' for your requirements.

Comment: For your discord example you may search keyword like "discursive meaning/semantics".